# If i want event driven server what to use libevent or libev?

Tags: c++, libevent

i want to make basic chat server using one of the event driven libarary .
but what to chose ? libevent or libev what is better ? which has better c++ support ?
which runes better in windows ? 
what is faster ? faster to develop and understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer libev. It's very minimalistic and some of the benchmarks (probably old) I've seen indicate it performs better. The documentation is also quite good.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer libevent because
1) it has an http server (both native one and [as an external project](https://github.com/ellzey/libevhtp)),
2) http client (really useful if you need your event-driven server to use external services); libev has one, but it won't compile for me with recent libev
3) dns server (I use it to automatically redirect traffic for high availability)
4) IMO, better docummentation
5) is better maintained (see 2)

Comment: libev has no http client, so both points 2) and 5) make no sense. besides, libev has a libevent compatibility layer, so external components designed for libevent (e.g. http clients or servers) have a high chance of working without any changes.

Comment: there was a client, but all right: if libev doesn't have the http client, then point 2 makes even more sense than I thought. and 5 is valid even without 2, i was just lazy to add more examples.

Answer (score 1):

The choice isn't just between libevent and libev. Boost.asio is excellent. The programming model works well, and it is integrated into Boost which you should be using anyway.

If you're just learning, you are unlikely to notice any speed differences caused by the library.